# ios Core Data Fetch a specific value

Tags: ios, core-data

So i am reading through Apple's Core Data Guide and questions on Stack and it is all correct but it is just not quite "clicking" in my head.

I have a BookShop that has a one-to-many relationship of Books.

I have entered in a BookShop called "Jenny's BookShop" and a BookShop called "BigWorld Books".

This is how i would add a 'new book' to a 'new bookshop':

> ```
> BookShop *myBookShop = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"BookShop" inManagedObjectContext:context];
>
> myBookShop.books = [[NSMutableSet alloc]init];
>
> Book *myBook = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Book" inManagedObjectContext:context];
>
> myBook.BookShop = myBookShop;
> ```
>
> [myBookShop addBookObject:myBook];

Say i want a Book to belong to only "BigWorld Books" and not to "Jenny's BookShop".

I am assuming i use a fetch request and grab a pointer to "BigWorld Books" and then assign a book to this particular bookshop? This is where i keep messing it up.

If someone could explain this "slowly" that would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

**Answer:**

> ```
>         NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name == %@"];
>         [request setPredicate:predicate];
>         [request setFetchLimit:1];
>         BookShop *resultBookShop = [[_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] lastObject];
>         [myBook setBookShop:resultBookShop];
> ```

Comment: How are you "messing up?" What is going wrong? Errors? Nil values?

Comment: I am just not accomplishing my goal which is to successfully only add particular Books to particular BookShops. Every time i add a Book to a BookShop it seems to add to all BookShops. Do you want an example snippet of code? The reason i haven't posted up code already is i want to see how somebody else would do it as opposed to just fixing up mine.

Comment: Other question that helped me out:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11572096/core-data-issue-checking-if-item-exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//if BookShop with name BigWorld Books not existed, create. If existed, use it
BookShop *bookshop = [self isExistedEntityWitName:@"BigWorld Books" entity:@"BookShop"];
if(!bookshop){
  //insertNewObjectForEntityForName
}else{
  //bookshop is existed
  //insert new book
  Book *b = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Book"
                                             inManagedObjectContext:context];
  //add new book (b) to NSSet of bookshop, and you have NSSet *books
  bookshop.books = books;
}
```

Comment: I have used this and another answer i found on stack to fully answer this question, thanks! I will post up what i did and mark correct in a bit!